# Using JSF for microservice based UI composition from different remote servers

Tags: user-interface, jsf, glassfish, microservices

I am currently working on a project where we try to slice a monolitic 3-Layer Web application into different microservices.
The web server is glassfish and frontend is based on JSF (templating etc).

What we want to do: We have different Microservices (hosted on different glassfish servers, using REST for communication). Each MS has its own UI. One Microservice (FrontendMicroservice) is in charge for the UserLogin and the dynamic composition of the various UI's depending on the logged in User. (E.g. Storemanger logged in -> StoreMicroserviceUI and ProductMicroserviceUI have to be loaded into FrontendMicroservice OR Enterprisemanger is logged in -> EnterpriseManager MicroserviceUI and ProductMicroserviceUI have to be loaded into FrontendMicroservice).
The FrontendMicroservice provides the frame with a Navigation/Menu Bar etc.

Is JSF  appropriate for this task? And which tags can be used? I could not find any similar approach using JSF!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is JSF appropriate for this task?

Sure

> And which tags can be used?

Any that will help you design the UI, just like with plain html. How you compose e.g. a 'full' page out of smaller pages is up to you. Do you want to use templates? You have to decide. You could use `ui:include` with a resource resolver, iframes but also use real (jsf based) portlets if that helps. But effectively this is not really a question for Stackoverflow.

> I could not find any similar approach using JSF!

That is because it mostly UIX https://ux.stackexchange.com/ initially. And when you know some of the basic features of a technology (facelets for jsf in this case), it is sort of 'logical' how to do it and you hence won't find lots of howtos or similar